# Unknown column 'pov.products_options_id' in 'having clause' error in having mysql query

Tags: mysql, having

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.products_image,
                p.products_quantity,
                m.manufacturers_id,
                p.products_id,
                pd.products_name,
                p.products_price,
                p.products_tax_class_id,
                p.products_price_sorter,
                p.products_qty_box_status,
                p.master_categories_id
FROM products p
LEFT JOIN manufacturers m USING(manufacturers_id)
LEFT JOIN products_description pd ON p.products_id = pd.products_id
JOIN products_to_categories p2c ON p.products_id = p2c.products_id
JOIN categories c ON p2c.categories_id = c.categories_id
LEFT JOIN meta_tags_products_description mtpd ON mtpd.products_id= p2c.products_id
AND mtpd.language_id = 2
JOIN products_attributes p2a ON p.products_id = p2a.products_id
JOIN products_options po ON p2a.options_id = po.products_options_id
JOIN products_options_values pov ON p2a.options_values_id = pov.products_options_values_id
WHERE (p.products_status = 1
       AND pd.language_id = 2
       AND ((pd.products_name LIKE '%t%'
             OR p.products_model LIKE '%t%'
             OR m.manufacturers_name LIKE '%t%'
             OR (mtpd.metatags_keywords LIKE '%t%'
                 AND mtpd.metatags_keywords !='')
             OR (mtpd.metatags_description LIKE '%t%'
                 AND mtpd.metatags_description !='')
             OR pd.products_description LIKE '%t%')))
GROUP BY p.products_id
HAVING sum(pov.products_options_id IN (12, 20)
           AND pov.products_options_values_id IN (91,82)) > 0
ORDER BY p.products_sort_order,
         pd.products_name;
```

Comment: When you use having clause and if the column used in the having is not in the select then you get this error, since the having will be evaluated after the data is selected. So you need to have  `pov.products_options_id` in the select list.

Comment: @Abhik Chakraborty - great . i have it not seen

Comment: here is database table http://indiadevdarshan.com/sql.txt

Comment: Abhik Chakraborty , can you please clear more, Thank you

Comment: Abhik Chakraborty, I am waiting for your reply, please clear more with query, Thank you or any one can help me?

Answer (score 0):

change HAVING

**from**

```
HAVING sum(pov.products_options_id IN (12, 20)
           AND pov.products_options_values_id IN (91,82)) > 0
```

**to**

```
HAVING pov.products_options_id IN (12, 20)
           AND pov.products_options_values_id IN (91,82)
```

Why you using > 0 ? you are using IN()

Comment: Still same Error Unknown column 'pov.products_options_id' in 'field list'

Comment: sorry, i have seen that you are using MyISAM ENGINE. Do you know that MyISAM only has FULL TABLE LOCK on INSERT / UPDATE AND DELETE. So if you modify your data , no other client can read from this tables. When is possible use INNODB Engine. Have you seen the Comment from @Abhik Chakraborty

Comment: thank you, can you please, please give me query which work with having, without having query working, but not showing proper result